# how to build my scrapy spider to an exe file using py2exe?

Tags: python, exe, scrapy, py2exe

I use scrapy to create a project and add my own spider, say "spider_us.py", in the "spiders" folder, and I want to build an exe file which can be executed in other computers without installing scrapy.

When I follow the instructions of py2exe, I make a new file "Setup.py" in the same folder with following content:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console = ["spider_us.py"])
```

however, it didn't work, since when I run my spider, I use the command "scrapy crawl spider_us" rather than directly running the file "spider_us.py" in the "spiders" folder.

how is it possible to build the entire spider program (automatically created by scrapy when I use "scrapy startproject XXX") to an exe file, not only the spider file ("spider_us.py" in my case) in the "spiders" subfolder.

Anyone gives some advise or help, any comment is welcomed. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

Try running the spiders through a Python script (instead of the command `scrapy crawl <spider_name>`). You'll need to write some code, e.g.:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = FollowAllSpider(domain='scrapinghub.com')
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the spider_closed signal was sent
```

For details, see [the documentations on "Run Scrapy from a script"](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)